# is ManageNameID supported by Spring Saml?

Tags: spring-saml

I am currently looking to use Spring Security Saml to replace OpenSSO SP.  I had seen that you have AuthnRequest but I could not see the ManageNameIDResponse anywhere.  This is where the IDP would send to SP ManageNameIDRequest with the nameID and Terminate then SP would have to send back ManageNameIDResponse which have successful message in it.  I attached sample of request from IDP and response SP for this case.

If it is not support, am I able to use openSaml to complete this use case?

Example of ManageNameIDRequest:

`
    http://edpapc111.abc.com:8102/catssoidp
    LvxIz/KrJUrABu9Y7/GajWS5NkJQ
        '

Example of ManageNameIDResponse

'
    https://applications.company.com:443/catssowlbx/user
    
        
        
            Request is done successfully
        
    
'

Answer (score 0):

The ManagedNameId protocol is not supported by Spring SAML. But it wouldn't be hard to add it, or implement stand-alone with OpenSAML.